# Seeking R Packages and Resources for Incremental/Online/Continuous Learning Algorithms

Tags: r

I'm working on a project involving large and evolving datasets and I'm interested in using incremental, online, or continuous learning algorithms in R. Can anyone recommend well-maintained R packages for implementing these algorithms? Additionally, any resources (tutorials, blog posts, papers, etc.) explaining their usage would be greatly appreciated.

Looking forward to your suggestions!